# jQuery equivalent of underscore.js' groupBy

Tags: jquery, arrays, underscore.js

Is there a built in function in jQuery that does the equivalent of http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy ?

Any workarounds?

Thanks

Comment: There is no jQuery equivalent built in. Feel free to create one yourself and share it though.

Comment: Damn that was my answer too.

Comment: I wanted to hack around a jQuery alternative but I was quickly discouraged

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery array group by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14427659/jquery-array-group-by)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. jQuery was not made for data handling, but for DOM, Ajax and Animations - those [utility functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/utilities/) as `each`, `map` or `grep` which are needed internally suck.

Use Underscore, there is nothing wrong with it! If you don't want to load the whole script, you can easily copy the [`groupby` function from the source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-42) to wherever you need it. Don't forget to add a comment on its origin.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a **jQuery** adaptation of [squint's native Javascript answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578814/groupby-in-javascript-to-group-json-data-and-populate-on-optgroup/8578875#8578875):

```
$.fn.groupBy = function(predicate) {
  var $array = $(this),
      grouped = {};

  $.each($array, function (idx, obj) {
    var $obj = $(obj);
        groupKey = predicate($obj);
    if (typeof(grouped[groupKey]) === "undefined") {
      grouped[groupKey] = $();
    }
    grouped[groupKey] = grouped[groupKey].add($obj);
  });

  return grouped;
}
```

### ^This returns a hash of { key_name: jQueryObjects }

---

And usage, in this case, to **group elements (`$yourElements`) by the HTML `name` attribute**:

```
var groupedByName = $yourElements.groupBy(function (obj) {
  return $(obj).attr('name');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used this, and it worked for me perfectly

```js
function groupBy(array, keyOrIterator) {
  var iterator, key;

  // use the function passed in, or create one
  if(typeof key !== 'function') {
    key = String(keyOrIterator);
    iterator = function (item) { return item[key]; };
  } else {
    iterator = keyOrIterator;
  }

  return array.reduce(function (memo, item) {
    var key = iterator(item);
    memo[key] = memo[key] || [];
    memo[key].push(item);
    return memo;
  }, {});
}
```

from [Link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/66752/214853)