# jquery array group by

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have array like this

```
abcArr = [["A", 10], ["B", 20], ["A",30],["C",40]]
```

how can I group and sum values by A, B, C...

```
$.each(abcArr , function() {
    if (this[0] == this[0]) { 
      this[1] + this[1] 
    }; // I know this will simple double [1] values :(
});
```

desired result should be

```
[["A", 40], ["B", 20], ["C",30]]
```

Comment: Are you willing to use underscore.js?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's a plain javascript way to do it that collects the unique indexes in a map and totals them as it does, then regenerates the array with the totals:

```
abcArr = [["A", 10], ["B", 20], ["A",30],["C",40]];

var items = {}, base, key;
for (var i = 0; i < abcArr.length; i++) {
    base = abcArr[i];
    key = base[0];
    // if not already present in the map, add a zeroed item in the map
    if (!items[key]) {
        items[key] = 0;
    }
    // add new item to the map entry
    items[key] += base[1];
}

// Now, generate new array
var outputArr = [], temp;
for (key in items) {
    // create array entry for the map value
    temp = [key, items[key]]
    // put array entry into the output array
    outputArr.push(temp);
}

// outputArr contains the result
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/vPMwu/

---

Here's a way using jQuery's `.each`:

```
abcArr = [["A", 10], ["B", 20], ["A",30],["C",40]];

var items = {}, base, key;
$.each(abcArr, function(index, val) {
    key = val[0];
    if (!items[key]) {
        items[key] = 0;
    }
    items[key] += val[1];
});

var outputArr = [];
$.each(items, function(key, val) {
    outputArr.push([key, val]);
});

// outputArr contains the result
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(outputArr);
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Q8LLT/

Comment: You beat me in speed, and I can't see how to beat you in quality with just pure javascript. +1

Comment: it's works... thank you very much, I will take a time to try to understand function... thank you

Comment: @InTry are you still interested in an underscore.js two-liner?

Comment: If you have a time, why not... I have looked on underscore page, its  "groupBy" function?  I did not give a try

Comment: @InTry groupBy, then do some mapping. I'm giving it a try right now.

Comment: @InTry - I fixed the jQuery version.

Comment: @InTry added a fuctional-style solution using Underscore

Comment: @jfriend00,  yes it's work as expected, thank you very much Sir

Answer (score 6):

[Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#) has `groupBy`, and the rest can be done by `map`ping over `reduce` (that is, reducing each group to one element

```
abcArr = [["A", 10], ["B", 20], ["A",30],["C",40]]

var grouped = _.groupBy(abcArr, function(x){return x[0]})
var result  = _.map(grouped, function(x){
    return _.reduce(x, function(x,y){
        return [y[0], x[1]+y[1]];
    }, [,0])
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/srvKQ/

Or (minified)

```
abcArr = [["A", 10], ["B", 20], ["A",30],["C",40]]

var result = _.map(
    _.groupBy(abcArr, function(x){return x[0]}),
    function(x){return _.reduce(
        x, function(x,y){return [y[0], x[1]+y[1]]}, [,0]
)});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/srvKQ/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce()` and `Map()`.

```js
var abcArr= [["A", 10], ["B", 20], ["A",30],["C",40]]

var groupValues = abcArr.reduce(function (obj, item) {
    obj[item[0]] = obj[item[0]] || [];
    obj[item[0]] = +obj[item[0]] + +item[1]; // add (+) before variable so it's cast to numeric 
    return obj;
}, {});

var groupData = Object.keys(groupValues).map(function (key) {
    return [key, groupValues[key]];
});

console.log(groupData)
```