# GroupBy data in an array- Javascript of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, group-by

I have some data in an array. I want to groupby the data based on a specific column. Please note, its not sorting that I want.

Example:

```
Name    Dept
AAA         D1
BBB         D2
CCC         D1
DDD         D2
EEE         D1
FFF         D2
```

I want to groupby the data based on dept. SO the output should be as below:

```
Name Dept
AAA  D1
CCC  D1
EEE  D1
BBB  D2
DDD  D2
FFF  D2
```

I want to implement this using jQuery\Javascript. This is to populate a grid with data, and there are around 8 columns, though I have just shown two columns in the above example. The idea here is to groupby a specific column, say Dept .

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14427659/jquery-array-group-by

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
var objects = [
    {Name: "AAA", Dept: "D1"},
    {Name: "BBB", Dept: "D2"},
    {Name: "CCC", Dept: "D1"},
    {Name: "DDD", Dept: "D2"},
    {Name: "EEE", Dept: "D1"},
    {Name: "FFF", Dept: "D2"}
];

var sorted = {};
for(var k in objects){
    var obj = objects[k];

    // Create new Group key if not exist
    if(!sorted[obj.Dept])
        sorted[obj.Dept] = [];

    sorted[obj.Dept].push(obj);
}

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand this is sorting. But I want to groupby. Because my real data may not contain D1 or D2. We cannot use > operator. Not sure if am correct !

Comment: So you asked it wrongly. You want that ALL 'Dept' stay in the same key?

Comment: Ya, Thats what I have shown in the example. May be i did not convey my message properly...

Comment: If it's not like that, it must be like this. Your question is not clear