# How to fetch region wise country list from JSON file using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

JSON format

```
[{"name": "Sri Lanka","region":"Asia"}, {"name": "India","region":"Asia"}, {"name": "kenya","region":"Africa"}, {"name": "Zimbabwe","region":"Africa"}]
```

I wanted to display as below

- **Africa**
- Kenya
- Zimbabwe
- **Asia**
- India
- Sri Lanka

Comment: If you can change the JSON you really should do `{ "regions":{ "Africa":[...,...,...],"Asia":[...,...,...]))`

Comment: [Here's a way using jQuery's .each][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14427807/3016125

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "Sri Lanka",
  "region": "Asia"
}, {
  "name": "India",
  "region": "Asia"
}, {
  "name": "Kenya",
  "region": "Africa"
}, {
  "name": "Zimbabwe",
  "region": "Africa"
}];

$.each(data, function(key, val) {
  // if `body` does not already have `ul` having
  // `class` `region` , append `ul` with first `name`
  // utilize `b` element as "header" for `ul` ,
  // to render `region` "header" above `ul` `li` `name`s
  if (!$("body ul." + val.region).is("*")) {
    $("<ul />", {
      "class": val.region,
      "html": "<li>" + val.name + "</li>"
    })
    .appendTo("body")
    .before("<b class=" + val.region + ">" + val.region + "</b>");
  } else {
    // if `b` `textContent` is `region` ,
    // append remaining `name` to `ul` that follows `b`
    $("b." + val.region).each(function() {
      if (this.textContent === val.region) {
        $(this).next("ul").append("<li>" + val.name + "</li>")
      }
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: @ManasRanjanPradhan Can create separate Question for _"scroll functionality"_ , include description , what tried , expected result ?

Comment: i have posted it as a separate question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30284658/how-to-scroll-to-a-dynamic-element

Comment: The code you have shared for fetching the JSON data is working fine for FF, Chrome, IE10. But for IE8 it is not working. Is there any other way for that ???

Comment: @ManasRanjanPradhan Unfortunately , do not currently have access to ie8  environment to test. According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8 , ie8 released 2009 ? ; perhaps suggest to ie8 users to update to at least ie10 ?

Comment: i am trying to wrap the "<b>" and "<ul>" with "<li>" using wrapAll(), but its only wraping the "<b>" element. Is there any other way to do that ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578504/how-to-wrap-2-dynamic-html-element-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to sort by region name then by country name, proceed as follows.

First, transform the array of countries into an object, properties of which are of arrays of countries. This  intermediate step is simpler than transforming directly to an array of regions.

```
var regions = {};
$.each(countries, function(i, obj) {
    if(!regions[obj.region]) {
        regions[obj.region] = [];
    }
    regions[obj.region].push(obj.name);
});
```

Then, transform the `regions` object into a sorted array of regions.

```
var sortedRegions = $.map(regions, function(value, key) {//key is a region name, value is an array of the region's countries
    value.sort(function(a, b) { return a.toUpperCase() > b.toUpperCase(); });//sort the arrays of countries alphabetically
    return {'region': key, 'countries': value};
}).sort(function(a, b) { return a.region.toUpperCase() > b.region.toUpperCase(); });//sort the mapped array of regions alphabetically
```

Then transform `sortedRegions` into the required HTML.

```
var html = sortedRegions.reduce(function(html_1, r) {
    return html_1 + r.countries.reduce(function(html_2, c) {
        return html_2 + '<li>' + c + '</li>';
    }, '<li>' + r.region + '</li><li><ul>') + '</ul></li>';
}, '<ul>') + '</ul>';
```

Now you can push the HTML into the DOM :

```
$("#myContainer").html(html);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jnzuqt3y/)**