# How to wrap two dynamic HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I have the below jquery where i have created the dynamic html structure

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "Afghanistan",
  "code": "A"
}, {
  "name": "AndorrA",
  "code": "A"
}, {
  "name": "Bouvet Island",
  "code": "B"
}, {
  "name": "Cook Islands",
  "code": "C"
}];
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
  if (!$("#aZContent ul." + val.code).is("*")) {
    $("<ul />", {
        "class": val.code,
        "html": "<li>" + val.name + "</li>"
      })
      .appendTo("#aZContent ol")
      .before('<b class=' + val.code + '>' + val.code + '</a></b>');
  } else {
    $("b." + val.code).each(function() {
      if (this.textContent === val.code) {
        $(this).next("ul").append("<li>" + val.name + "</li>");
      }
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="aZContent">
  <ol></ol>
</div>
```

How to wrap the "b" and "ul" element with "li"

```
<li>
  <b></b>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Where is aZContent? Maybe it would be also helpful to have the value of `data` that we can reproduce what you are doing there. A working fiddle would be even better

Comment: Please have a look, i have added the working fiddle @Michel Walter

Comment: @ManasRanjanPradhan See post.

Comment: @guest271314 Please have a look need your guidance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604491/how-to-expand-collapse-for-a-nested-dynamic-list-using-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try utilizing `$.each()`, `.appendTo()`, `.append()`; setting `ol li` , `b` `class` to `code` property of `data`.

```js
$(function() {
  var data = [{
    "name": "Afghanistan",
    "code": "A"
  }, {
    "name": "Bouvet Island",
    "code": "B"
  }, {
    "name": "Cook Islands",
    "code": "C"
  }];

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    if (!$("#aZContent ul." + val.code).is("*")) {
      // append `<li>` to `ol`
      $("<li />", {
          // set `class` to `val.code`
          "class": val.code,
          // set `li` `html` to `b` , `ul` , `li`
          "html": "<b class=" + val.code + ">" +
            val.code + "</a></b>" +
            "<ul><li>" +
            val.name + "</li></ul>"
        })
        .appendTo("#aZContent ol")
    } else {
      $("b." + val.code).each(function() {
        if (this.textContent === val.code) {
          // append `li` to `ul`
          $(this).next("ul").append("<li>" + val.name + "</li>");
        }
      })
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="aZContent">
  <ol></ol>
</div>
```

Comment: when it comes to more data its distorted like separate list instead of coming under the letter. Please have a look http://jsfiddle.net/mrpradhan/Las6cvq9/1/

Comment: @ManasRanjanPradhan Yes . `data` at http://jsfiddle.net/mrpradhan/Las6cvq9/1/ not appear same as `data` at Question ?

Comment: @ManasRanjanPradhan `js` appear to meet requirement of _"How to wrap the "b" and "ul" element with "li"_ ?

Comment: i have added some data in my base question can you please chek that one how it appears.

Comment: @ManasRanjanPradhan Try adding `$("b:contains(A):gt(0), b:contains(B):gt(0), b:contains(C):gt(0)").css("color", "transparent");` below `$.each()` http://jsfiddle.net/Las6cvq9/2/

Comment: @ManasRanjanPradhan Note, _"how it appears"_ not appear to be mentioned at Question ? Question at OP appear to be _"How to wrap the "b" and "ul" element with "li""_  ?

Comment: ,i think  :contains(), :gt() does not supported in IE9/8

Comment: Is there any other way to do that ?