# How to expand/collapse (+/-) for a nested dynamic list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, toggle

i have tried the toggle function but i think selecting a the proper list is having some problem.

```js
var json ={"Asia": [{"regionList": [{"regionName": "Eastern Asia","Countrylist": [{"countryName": "China","subCountryList": [{"subCountryName": "Southern China"},{"subCountryName": "Eastern China"}]},{"countryName": "Hong Kong"}]},{"regionName": "Southern Asia","Countrylist": [{"countryName": "India"},{"countryName": "Pakistan"}]}]}]};
var html = '';
$.each(json, function(i1, object) {
  html += '<li><input type="checkbox" /><b class=' + i1 + ' ><a name="' + i1 + '" >' + i1 + '</a></b>';
    $.each(object, function(i2, continent) {
 html += '<ul>';
     $.each(continent.regionList, function(i3, region) {
     html += '<li><input type="checkbox" /><b>' + region.regionName + '</b>';
    $.each(region.Countrylist, function(i4, country) {
   html += '<ul><li class=' + country.countryName + '><input type="checkbox" />' + country.countryName;
   if (country.subCountryList) {
     $.each(country.subCountryList, function(i5, subCountry) {
    html += '<ul><li><input type="checkbox" />' + subCountry.subCountryName + '</li></ul>';
     });
    $("b." + country.countryName).toggle(function() {
     $(this).children('ul').slideUp();
    },
    function() {
     $(this).children('ul').slideDown();
    });
    };
    html += '</li></ul>';
     });
     html += '</li>';
   });
   html += '</ul>';
    });
    html += '</li>';
  });

  $('#regionContent ol').html(html);
```

```css
li, ol{list-style:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="regionContent">
  <ol></ol>
</div>
```

I wanted to add toggle function to the country name(China) which has sub countries(southern China). On Click of China it should collapse all the sub countries list with +/- sign and vice versa.

Comment: I would recommend using EJS template library use this source code https://www.dropbox.com/s/9thr3jpj6971s1x/testing.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

---

```js
var json = {
  "Asia": [{
    "regionList": [{
      "regionName": "Eastern Asia",
      "Countrylist": [{
        "countryName": "China",
        "subCountryList": [{
          "subCountryName": "Southern China"
        }, {
          "subCountryName": "Eastern China"
        }]
      }, {
        "countryName": "Hong Kong"
      }]
    }, {
      "regionName": "Southern Asia",
      "Countrylist": [{
        "countryName": "India"
      }, {
        "countryName": "Pakistan"
      }]
    }]
  }]
};
var html = '';
$.each(json, function(i1, object) {
  html += '<li><input type="checkbox" /><b class=' + i1 + ' ><a name="' + i1 + '" >' + i1 + '</a></b>';
  $.each(object, function(i2, continent) {
    html += '<ul>';
    $.each(continent.regionList, function(i3, region) {
      html += '<li><input type="checkbox" /><b>' + region.regionName + '</b>';
      $.each(region.Countrylist, function(i4, country) {
        html += '<ul><li class=' + country.countryName.replace(/\s/g, "-") + '><input type="checkbox" />' + country.countryName;
        
        if (country.hasOwnProperty("subCountryList") && country.subCountryList.length > 0) {
        html += '<span class=' + country.countryName.replace(/\s/g, "-") + '>-</span>';
          };
          
        $(document)
          .on("click", "input ~ span." + country.countryName.replace(/\s/g, "-") + ":first", function(e) {
            $(this).siblings("ul").is(":visible") ? $(this).siblings("ul").slideUp({
              start: function() {
                e.target.textContent = "+"
              }
            }) : $(this).siblings("ul").slideDown({
              start: function() {
                e.target.textContent = "-"
              }
            })
          });
        if (country.subCountryList) {
          $.each(country.subCountryList, function(i5, subCountry) {
            html += '<ul><li><input type="checkbox" />' + subCountry.subCountryName + '</li></ul>';

          });
        };
        html += '</li></ul>';
      });
      html += '</li>';
    });
    html += '</ul>';
  });
  html += '</li>';
});

$('#regionContent ol').html(html);
```

```css
li,
ol {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="regionContent">
  <ol></ol>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you but the functionality is little different. If the country(e.g. china) has sub country than it has a span with "-" sign. Then if we click on the "-" then it will collapse the sub country and add "+" sign. Currently its behave on click of the check box.

Comment: when i am trying to add more subcountries, the expand collapse is not working."subCountryList": [{"subCountryName": "Southern China"},{"subCountryName": "Eastern China"},{"subCountryName": "HongKong"} ]when i am trying to add more subcountries, the exand collapse is not working."subCountryList": [{"subCountryName": "Southern China"},{"subCountryName": "Eastern China"},{"subCountryName": "HongKong"} ]

Comment: @mrp Was original Question resolved ? , before attempting to _" add more subcountries"_ ? Why was "more subcountries" not included in original Question ? Can include link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ? Can include all relevant `js` , `html` at Question - instead of adding portions to `js` , `html` and Question - after initial Question resolved ?

Comment: i apologies for this, i thought if it can handle 1 data then it will handle all the data. It looks fine but the  "-" is in every country those who don't have the sub countries.

Comment: Thank you. But still its unable to handle more data like if the country "Hongkong" has sub countries, then the code is breaking.

Comment: Can create jsfiddle to demonstrate ?

Comment: i apologies, that was my mistake. The code works fine and able handle more data and again thanks a ton.