# Group the names when age are the same in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I am getting a list of members using jQuery and iterating over each of them to get a name and age. What I want to do is store the names together if they have the same age. Something like:

```
{
    31: { John, Mary },
    24: { Paul, Peter } 
}
```

I can't seem to store them correctly.

**EDIT**:

This is what I have so far:

```
$('span.members a').each(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('href'),
    success: function (result) {
      name = $(result).find('tr td:contains("Username:")').next().text().trim();
      age = $(result).find('tr td:contains("Age:")').next().text().trim();

    }
  });
});
```

**EDIT:**

This is the source HTML:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="96%" class="box" id="testProf" style="border-spacing:0;">
<tr>
    <td class="top" colspan="4">
        <a href="compare?b=JohnRandall">JohnRandall</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="padding:4px" width="100" height="1" align="left">
        Username:
    </td>
    <td style="padding:4px" height="1">
        <a href="compose?to=JohnRandall">JohnRandall</a>                                 
    </td>
    <td style="padding:4px" width="130" height="1">
        <a href="associates?uid=JohnRandall&as=Friend" style="color:#a6ffb5;">Add as friend</a>
    </td>
    <td width="300" style="padding:0px;margin:0;overflow:hidden;" rowspan="11" valign="top"><img src="//id.crimecdn.com/0gd74.jpg" width="300" style="display: block;max-height:2000px;"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
    <td style="padding:4px" align="left" height="1">
        Status:
    </td>
    <td style="padding:4px" height="1">
        <span style="color:#00ff00;" title="Online Now">&bull;</span> <span style="color:#00ff00;">Online</span>                               
    </td>
    <td style="padding:4px" height="1">
        <a href="associates?uid=JohnRandall&as=Blocked" style="color:#ffa6a6;">Add as enemy</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="padding:4px" align="left" height="1">
        Crew:                                </td>
    <td height="1">
        <a href="/crew/25" style="border:0;display: block;"><img src="//id.crimecdn.com/o7yft.jpg" width="59" height="33" style="border:0;display: block;"></a>                                
    </td>
    <td style="padding:4px" height="1">
        <a href="compose?to=JohnRandall">Send message</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
    <td style="padding:4px" align="left" height="1">
        Wealth:
    </td>
    <td style="padding:4px" height="1">
        Dangerously Healthy <a href="#" onClick="confirm('This player has between $10,000,000 to $50,000,000.');return false;" style="color:#888;">(?)</a>                                
    </td>
    <td style="padding:4px" height="1">
        <a href="bank?to=JohnRandall">Send money</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="padding:4px" align="left" height="1">
        Age:
    </td>
    <td style="padding:4px" height="1">
        28                                
    </td>
    <td style="padding:4px" height="1">
        <a href="escrow?to=JohnRandall">Send escrow</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
    <td style="padding:4px" align="left" height="1">
        Gender:
    </td>
    <td style="padding:4px" height="1">
        Male                                
    </td>
    <td style="padding:4px" height="1">
        <a href="kill.php?search=JohnRandall">Kill search</a>                                
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="padding:4px" align="left" height="1">
        Last Active:
    </td>
    <td style="padding:4px" height="1">
        Just now                                
    </td>
    <td style="padding:4px" height="1">
        <a href="compare?b=JohnRandall">Compare</a>                                
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
    <td style="padding:4px" align="left" height="1">
        Date Joined:
    </td>
    <td style="padding:4px" height="1">
        2015-12-16                                
    </td>
    <td style="padding:4px" height="1">
        !--overlord2.php?id=lookup&prefill=JohnRandall-->
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="padding:4px" align="left" height="1">
        Messages:
    </td>
    <td style="padding:4px" height="1">
        2                                
    </td>
    <td style="padding:4px" height="1">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="backdrop" style="padding: 4px;" colspan="3" height="1">
        <a href="edit" style="opacity:0.5;float:right;" class="hover"><img src="//caviar.dtmcdn.com/render/45865/12"> Edit my profile</a><p class="royal">Player quote</p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" valign="top" style="background-color:#2a2a2a !important;padding: 0 !important;">
        <div style="width:480px; overflow:hidden;">
            92                                    
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please add the list of members to the question; we need to see the data you're working from to help you. Also note that your child objects would be better as arrays.

Comment: I think you should use an array or arrays. Why not make use of the fact that arrays are already sorted by number? Also, please add the code you have already as its unlcear where the data is coming from and how you are processing it.

Comment: Use an array of objects. The array index is the age and the objects at that index contain the names

Comment: `Why not make use of the fact that arrays are already sorted by number?` There's no inherent sorting in place on an array.

Comment: Using `map` on array?

Comment: Create an array of objects?  Each object would have an "age" field and a "members" field.  The "members" field would be an array of the names.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes there is, you can make use of something cool called `indexes`, where the `indexes` represent the ages and the internal arrays represent the values.

Comment: That's a really convoluted way of doing something which can be achieved a lot more simply.

Comment: Does my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508368/how-to-store-all-names-together-when-age-is-the-same/35508423#35508423) help you in any way? If not, could you also give us the HTML of your table?

Comment: Wait, so for each anchor you're making an AJAX request and loading in some HTML? That's really inefficient.

Comment: Added the source HTML

Comment: @PaulKenny I updated my answer to also address how to proces your HTML input -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508368/group-the-names-when-age-are-the-same-in-javascript/35508423#35508423

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Step 1 : the target datastructure :

There are two issues with your data structure :

- You're forgetting to put the names between quotes. `John` should be `"John"`. `Mary` should be `"Mary"`. etc.
- You're trying to use an object for `[ "John", "Mary" ]` and `[ "Paul", "Peter" ]`, where you should be using an array.

So, the data structure you're looking for, is this :

```
{
    31 : [ "John", "Mary" ],
    24 : [ "Paul", "Peter" ]
}
```

---

#### Step 2 : fetching the data from the HTML input :

I suggest you make this small adjustment to your JavaScript code :

```
var source = [];

$('span.members a').each(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        success: function (result) {
            source.push({
                name : $(result).find('tr td:contains("Username:")').next().text().trim(),
                age : $(result).find('tr td:contains("Age:")').next().text().trim()
            });
        }
    });
});
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9pwr64ga/2/))

This fetches the data from your HTML input and puts it into a data structure that looks like this :

```
var source = [{
    name : "Paul",
    age : 24
}, {
    name : "Mary",
    age : 31
}, {
    name : "Peter",
    age : 24
}, {
    name : "John",
    age : 31
}];
```

---

#### Step 3 : converting to the right data structure :

Once you fetched all the data, you only need to convert your data from the source data structure to the target data structure, which is as simple as this :

```
var convert = function(source) {
    var output = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        if(output[source[i].age]) {
            output[source[i].age].push(source[i].name);
        } else {
            output[source[i].age] = [source[i].name];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/geyyjj8s/))

---

#### Putting the pieces of the puzzle together :

You have to wait with executing your `convert` function until all of your Ajax calls have finished.

For example, you could do something like ...

```
if (source.length === numberOfMembers) {
    target = convert(source);
}
```

... right behind the `source.push(...)` statement.

So if you put all the pieces of the puzzle together, you should get something like this :

```
var source = [];
var target;
var $members = $('span.members a');
var numberOfMembers = $members.size();

var convert = function(source) {
    var output = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        if(output[source[i].age]) {
            output[source[i].age].push(source[i].name);
        } else {
            output[source[i].age] = [source[i].name];
        }
    }
    return output;
}

$members.each(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        success: function (result) {
            source.push({
                name : $(result).find('tr td:contains("Username:")').next().text().trim(),
                age : $(result).find('tr td:contains("Age:")').next().text().trim()
            });
            if (source.length === numberOfMembers) {
                target = convert(source);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Source is now populated with data like this:
`Object { name="JohnRandall",  age="25"}, Object { name="Pain",  age="32"}, Object { name="Mayfair",  age="25"}, Object { name="Ghost",  age="14"}`

But output is a blank object.

Comment: @PaulKenny : You have to wait with executing step 3 until all of your Ajax calls have finished. For example, if you know the total amount of members you're going to process, you could do something like `if (source.length === numberOfMembers) { output = convert( source ) }` right behind the `source.push(...)` statement, where `convert` is a function that contains the code of step 3.

Comment: I have added step 3 in after the .each selector has finished. From `console.log(source)`, I can see that it is populated and should be ready to go into step 3.

Comment: @PaulKenny : I just updated my answer. Check the last section for how to put the pieces of the puzzle together.

Comment: Thank you so much John, you have really helped me out. One thing I don't get is why can't I call the function after step 3. Isn't .each() synchronous?

Comment: @PaulKenny : `$members.each(...)` is synchronous, but `$.ajax(...)` isn't. Each `$.ajax(...)` call is done asynchronously, which is why you have to wait with your conversion from source to target structure until the last `$.ajax(...)` call has completed.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you some idea of what to do:

```
abcArr = [["Paul", 24], ["Mary", 31], ["Peter",24],["John",31]];

var items = {}, base, key;
$.each(abcArr, function(index, val) {
    key = val[1];
    users = [];
    if (items[key]) {
        items[key].push(val[0]);
    }
    else {
        users.push(val[0])
      items[key] = users;
    }

});

var outputArr = [];
$.each(items, function(key, val) {
    outputArr.push([key, val]);
});

// outputArr contains the result
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(outputArr);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rennomarcus/7Lvy0w1t/

I got the idea from this topic: [jquery array group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14427659/jquery-array-group-by)