# Jquery array group by multiple elements and find total

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, grouping

I have an array like this:

```
abcArr = [["A", "dog", 10], ["B", "cat", 20], ["A", "dog", 30],["C", "pig", 40]] ["A", "cat", 30],  ["B", "cat", 20], ["A", "horse", 10];
```

I was looking at this post ([jquery array group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14427659/jquery-array-group-by)) and I need something similar for my issue but I need to group my array based on 2 elements.

So my answer should look like this:

```
[["A", "dog", 40], ["B", "cat", 40], ["C", "pig", 40]] ["A", "cat", 30], ["A", "horse", 10];
```

I tried @jfriend00 's `.each()` approach to group just one field and it works, but I don't know how to adapt it to use two fields to group the data above.

```js
abcArr = [["A", 10],["B", 20],["A", 30],["C", 40]];
var items = {},
  base, key;
$.each(abcArr, function(index, val) {
  key = val[0];
  if (!items[key]) {
    items[key] = 0;
  }
  items[key] += val[1];
});
var outputArr = [];
$.each(items, function(key, val) {
  outputArr.push([key, val]);
});

console.log(outputArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: @NewBee Can you please [edit] your post and include the code there?

Comment: I have tried @friend00 's .each approach. Code is included in the post.

Comment: The abcArr in the top example doesn't match the one in the runnable snipplet.

Comment: @NewBee Take a look at my solution and see if that's what you're looking for

Comment: @Taplar The working example only groups by 1 field, OP's new use case requires grouping by 2 fields and doesn't know how to bridge the gap between the working solution and what they need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is, instead of one field being used as the key for your `items` object, you can combine multiple keys, like so:

*Note* - jQuery is not necessary to solve this issue because JavaScript has the handy [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) functions built right in.

```js
var abcArr = [["A", "dog", 10], ["B", "cat", 20], ["A", "dog", 30],["C", "pig", 40], ["A", "cat", 30],  ["B", "cat", 20], ["A", "horse", 10]];

// group the items by letter-animal and sum the results
var items = abcArr.reduce(function (results, current) {
  var letter = current[0];
  var animal = current[1];
  var value = current[2];
  
  // combine the two fields as the key to match on.. this is where the magic happens
  var key = letter + "-" + animal;
  if (!results[key]) {
    results[key] = 0;
  }
  results[key] += value;
  return results;
}, {});

// break the keys out from the hyphenated form back into individual array elements w/ value
var outputArr = Object.keys(items).map(function (key) {
  var splitKey = key.split("-");
  var letter = splitKey[0];
  var animal = splitKey[1];
  var itemValue = items[key];
  
  return [letter, animal, itemValue];
});

console.log(outputArr);
```

Alternatively with ES6 Syntax:

```js
var abcArr = [["A", "dog", 10], ["B", "cat", 20], ["A", "dog", 30],["C", "pig", 40], ["A", "cat", 30],  ["B", "cat", 20], ["A", "horse", 10]];

var items = abcArr.reduce((results, [letter, animal, value]) => {
  var key = letter + "-" + animal;
  if (!results[key]) {
    results[key] = 0;
  }
  results[key] += value;
  return results;
}, {});

var outputArr = Object.keys(items).map(key => [...key.split("-"), items[key]]);

console.log(outputArr);
```