# Group array of items using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I group items inside of a loop using jQuery?

I have these items like these in each loop iteration:

```
['ab', 'sd']
['ab', 'dc']
['ab', 'ca']
['bc', 'ds']
['bc', 'ea']
```

And I need to have an output like this:

```js
{'ab':[sd,dc,ca],'bc':[ds,ea]}
```

I tried to filter them, but I couldn't achieve this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14427659/jquery-array-group-by

Comment: This is not list that exact things this is loop array each array inside loop that loop how to make group  ['ab', 'sd'], ['ab', 'dc'],['ab', 'ca'], ['bc', 'ds'],  ['bc', 'ea'], ['bc','ea',ta]
output {'ab':[sd,dc,ca],'bc':[ds]{'ea',[ta]} like this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jquery array group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14427659/jquery-array-group-by)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1 way you can do it is like this:

```
$.each(input, function(i, n) {
  var keyW = n[0];
  if (output[keyW] == undefined) {
    output[keyW] = [];
  }

  if ($.inArray(n[1], output[keyW]) === -1) {
    output[keyW].push(n[1])
  }

})
```

**Demo**

```js
var input = [
  ['ab', 'sd'],
  ['ab', 'dc'],
  ['ab', 'ca'],
  ['bc', 'ds'],
  ['bc', 'ea'],
  ['bc', 'ea']
];


var output = {};


$.each(input, function(i, n) {
  var keyW = n[0];
  if (output[keyW] == undefined) {
    output[keyW] = [];
  }

  if ($.inArray(n[1], output[keyW]) === -1) {
    output[keyW].push(n[1])
  }

})


console.log(output)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is works only two array only what about third one when ever if third value also is same then create inner child array 

example : ['VSB', 'Agent']
 ['VSB', 'Agent Procedure']
 ['VSB', 'Anti-Malware']
['TraverseOut', 'Devices']
 ['TraverseOut', 'Signatures']
['BS', 'HR']
 ['BS', 'Finance']
['AnuuthAnvil', 'On-Demand', '2FA']
 ['AuthAnvil', 'On-Premise', '2fa']
 ['Unigma', 'Monitor']
 ['Unigma', 'Report']
 ['365 Command', 'Monitor']
['365 Command', 'Report']

Comment: @Methababu 3 array was not part of your original question.