# How to merge the same value

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I need some help. I would like to merge something like this 12,12,12,13,13,14,14,14,15,15 into 12,13,14,15. i have this code so far.

```
 if ($('#branchName' + branchList.branch).length == 0) {
                    $('#zzz').append(
                        '<span>' + branchList.branch + '</span>' +
                            '<ul id="branchName' + branchList.branch + '">' +
                            '<li>' +
                            '<span id="combo' + branchList.combo + '">' + branchList.combo + '</span>' +
                            '</li>' +
                            '</ul>');
                    if ($('#combo' + branchList.combo).length == 0) {
                        //if exists go to else
                    } else {
                        //append combo
                    }
                }

                else {
                    $('#branchName' + branchList.branch).append(
                        '<li>' +
                            '<span id="combo' + branchList.combo + '">' + branchList.combo + '</span>' +
                            '</li>');           
                }
```

Update : I already merge the numbers on my if else by appending it on existing one.  Now my problem is where should I put again the next if statement for my combo.

Comment: What's inside data? Is it an object or an array?

Comment: can u pls explain little more.. what u mean by given sample.. can you pls explain little more.

Comment: i think you need to group by the numbers 1-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14427659/jquery-array-group-by 2-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203778/jquery-equivalent-of-underscore-js-groupby

Comment: @Mzn it is an array..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the filter property.
Say that you have those values in an array

```
arr=[1,1,1,2,3,4,5];
new_arr = arr.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return arr.indexOf(item) === pos;
});
```

The [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), takes a callback function and calls it on each element of the array, like .map and takes at-most three argument, the value of the element(from your array), the index and the Array itself.

The idea behind this is, you take the one element then check if the indexOf(that_element) is equal to the position of the element.

**Walkthrough.**

> step 1: indexOf(1) = 0 and pos = 0, indexOf(1) === pos // true so the element is pushed in the new_arr
> step 2: indexOf(1) = 0 and pos = 1, // condition false, so discard.

so on..

This property of allowing and discarding probably comes from duck-typing

Comment: You should probably mention you got that answer from __[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array/9229821#9229821)__.

Comment: oh looks like simple.. gonna try this.. ty

Comment: yow inside that function is the parameter? (item,pos)

Comment: explain what you mean. did you read the doc link?

Comment: i tried this, but that is not the answer... im trying nested if

Comment: you need to provide more details then. It didn't work doesnot give much detail. Because the code does remove the duplicate elements.

Comment: @argentum47 ty. I already merge the numbers on my if else by appending it on existing one, not removing it. Now my problem is where should I put again the next if statement for my combo, because there is duplicate again.

Comment: @argentum47 my output above 
Branch1 =
Combo1, Combo1, Combo2,Combo2.
Branch2 = Combo1, Combo1, Combo2,Combo2

my next output should be as Branch1 = Combo1,Combo2. Branch2= Combo1,Combo2.

Comment: @Cerbrus sir, with due respect, there are multiple ways to do this, `filter` is one way , `using a hash` is another way. This problem is so common that any solution will match with another solution. If I write. use `Set` in es6 its going to be copy pasting MDN docs now.

Comment: @John https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array/9229821#9229821 please refer here for all possible approaches

Comment: Dude, this answer is 6 years old... Why are you even replying to it now?

Comment: @Cerbrus hahahaha.. sorry man. I came back on SO after 4 years. Its been so long I have actually helped and learned by helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can import a library [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq)
In Underscore, has a simple function to do this:

```
_.union([1, 2, 3], [101, 2, 1, 10], [2, 1]);
=> [1, 2, 3, 101, 10]
```

Comment: this is new knowledge to me.